# Asp.net MVC Async upload Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

We are working on a file upload and have chosen the blueimp plugin.  We have this working in the following way.

User selects all files they wish to upload and clicks a button to upload all in one go.

This part works fine and sends all files at once to the server.

The server code sample only is as follows.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload()
{
    var result = await new Uploader().UploadFile(Request.Files[0]);
    return Json(result);
}
public class Uploader
{
    public async Task<UploadResult> UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        //do file processing and save file to disk
        var filerecord = _fileService.GetById(xxxx);
        filerecord.files.Add(new Info { name = file.FileName, size = file.ContentLength });
        //Here for us its Mongo but any not sure what the result would be against another db
        await _fileService.SaveAsync(filerecord);
        return new UploadResult { message = "ok" };
    }
}

//js
    fi.fileupload({
        url: 'uploadfile',
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        singleFileUploads:false,
        maxNumberOfFiles: maxFiles,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(jpe?g)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 1048576*2, //1MB
        messages: { },
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: true,
        previewMaxWidth: 50,
        previewMaxHeight: 50,
        previewCrop: false,
        dropZone: $('#dropzone')
    });

    fi.on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {

        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            data.submit();
            return false;
        });
});
```

Just a note that the db in this case is Mongo

**The Problem**
Uploading single files at a time i.e select a file click upload all works as expected.
Select more than one file and hit upload button all files are uploaded and saved to the disk without an issue.  However I would expect the following behaviour

1. Get record from db
2. Add info about the file
3. Save the record

As mentioned this works great with one file at a time but when they all come in at once I am guessing the async behaviour causes the method to loose context of what file its working on as the 3 steps in the debugger seem to be called per file randomly rather than in order.

I have tried various approaches like change the order of the way things happen, also using ConfigureAwait etc.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I myself use multipart mime type and loops through all files uploaded. This way I can process each file uploaded accordingly

Comment: @John Ephraim do you think that as I am not checking the multipart and just saving the file using the file.SaveAs on PostedFile that this is what might be causing the randomness of the db side?

Comment: Nah, it shouldn't have any connection with the randomness. You are right about the behavior being caused by the async operation causing an unordered sequence of processing. Can you show more of your Upload method like how you exactly pass all the Request.Files to your Uploader.UploadFile?

Comment: @AliK: No, the `async` wouldn't cause those steps to get out of order. With the code you posted, it's not possible to do those steps out of order. It is possible for them to interleave - i.e., it could get the db record for the second file *while* the first one is saving, but they wouldn't be random or lose context of what file they're working on.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado I am passing the files exactly as I have displayed using the Request.Files[0] which is always the first file that comes in as I do not get more than one because I don't set multiple on form just allow multiple uploads by selecting one at a time and posting all in one go.

Comment: @StephenCleary That I agree as I have used async in many places and worked with a number of api's with no issues and that is why I am finding this strange and have been on it for a long time now.  My only alternative is to allow the file to auto upload as soon as its selected by the user which works great but I don't see this as a solution but rather a workaround which does not solve the issue just avoids it.

Comment: @AliK: Create a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You'll probably find where the problem is somewhere along the way.

Comment: @StephenCleary I have added the js exactly as i have it and if run with the scripts from blueimp you will find all files are submitted in one go as i mentioned the issue seems to occur at the db not being updated as expected the db can be anything i'm guessing but not sure if sql server would produce the same result as can't test this from our side yet.  If it runs fine with any other db i'm guessing it might be a Mongo issue as they have introduced all methods as Async but I am not sure this would be the case.

Comment: @AliK: A minimal, reproducible example is the *smallest* amount of code that reproduces the problem. Ideally, something that other people can copy/paste into Visual Studio and reproduce locally.

Comment: @StephenCleary I have provided all the code apart from the html form and the db access layer the update class and the controller and the jquery that just points to the fileupload, using this it would not take 5 mins to set up a new app to do exactly what i'm doing.  If something is not clear let me know.  Appreciate the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your case correctly this code should work for you:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload()
{
    var files = new HttpPostedFileBase[Request.Files.Count];
    Request.Files.CopyTo(files, 0);
    var tasks = files.Select(f=>new Uploader().UploadFile(f));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return Json(tasks.Where(v=>v.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion ).Select(v=>v.Result).ToList());
}
```

Comment: There is no Select on the files collection.